# PHP convert 64 bit printable number to 8 byte binary string?

Tags: php

The following function, given 8 bytes, will convert them to one 64 bit printable number:

```
function extract($raw_db_data)
{
    $bc_val = "0";
    for ($j = 7; $j >= 0; --$j) {
        $byte_val = ord(substr($raw_db_data, $j, 1));
        $bc_val = bcadd(bcmul("$bc_val", "256", 0), "$byte_val", 0);
    }
    return $bc_val;
}
```

I am trying to implement the reverse of the above function, so given a printable 64 bit number it should generate one 8 byte binary string.

I tried the PHP's pack but it fails to work on 32 bit systems with 64 bit numbers.

Comment: `bcmul("$bc_val", "256", 0)` <-- what this means? You're multiplying every byte by 256 :-S

Comment: @zerkms: It means, multiply the `$bc_val` with `256` and don't keep any decimal digit.

Comment: Okay. It means that. What does it have to do with your task though? Why do you think it is what you need to do to reconstruct a number?

Comment: @zerkms: I am multiplying everything with 256, yes. While the above code works and it's correct, maybe there is a better way to do the same task, though.

Comment: Yep, my fault, I confused `$bc_val` with `$byte_val` (naming is hard indeed). So what's wrong with this code then?

Comment: @zerkms: It works as expected, I am trying to create the reverse of the above code.

Comment: You're trying, okay. What do you expect from community?

Comment: @zerkms: I tried to edit the above code but failed. Instead of posting a non working version I decided to post the reverse of what I am trying to do.

Comment: So that someone wrote complete code for you? What kind of *help* do you need?

Comment: @zerkms: No, so that someone gave me suggestion or modified the existing code.

Comment: Well, just implement an algorithm that does the opposite operations. Hint: `bcdiv` + `bcmod`

Comment: @zerkms: If I could do that I would have posted a question here. While I understand more or less what the above code does, I don't understand how to modify it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Take the modulus of division by 256. It's the 1st byte. Then divide a number by 256. Repeat. And don't "modify" but rewrite from scratch, it's just 4 lines.

Comment: @zerkms: Thanks for the help. I replaced the for loop with `for ($j = strlen($raw_db_data); $j >= 0; --$j)` , left the `$byte_val = ord(substr($raw_db_data, $j, 1));` unchanged and replaced the last line with `$bc_val = bcadd(bcmod("$bc_val", "256", 0), "$byte_val", 0);` but I get wrong results...

Comment: Well, I suggested you to rewrite it from the scratch when you revert it, not just replace it parts. Not sure why you even have `bcadd` there. Just take a piece of paper and try to do all the maths manually.

Comment: @zerkms: I am trying but still I can't get it to work. Any more help is really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to do it manually on the paper with 2 or 3 bytes number?

Comment: @zerkms: I am trying by reading this: http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @zerkms mentioned in the comments, you want to perform the inverse operations.

```
function unextract($bc_val)
{
    $bytes = '';
    while ($bc_val) {
        $bytes .= chr(bcmod($bc_val, "256"));
        $bc_val = bcdiv($bc_val, "256");
    }
    return $bytes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I replaced the loop with `while ($bc_val != '0')` otherwise it's an endless loop.

Comment: I noticed, the output size, if I use strlen is not 8 bytes always as it should and there are '0' at the end. Is it safe to use `$bytes = substr($bytes, 0, 8);`